# Connection between uniqueness of Jordan normal form and Jordan–Chevalley decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $f$ be an endomorphism of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$.

> **Definition.**
> A *Jordan–Chevalley decomposition* of $f$ is a decompositon $f = d + n$ where $d$ and $n$ are endomorphisms of $V$ such that $d$ is diagonalizable, $n$ is nilpotent, and $d$ and $n$ commute with each other.

It is known that $f$ admits a Jordan–Chevalley decomposition if and only if it admits a Jordan normal form.
More explicitely, if $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $V$ such that the representing matrix $[f]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is in Jordan normal form, then $[d]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is the diagonal part of $[f]_{\mathcal{B}}$ and $[n]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is the strictly upper triangular part of $[f]_{\mathcal{B}}$.

The Jordan–Chevalley decomposition of $f$ is unique, and the Jordan normal form is unique up to permutation of the Jordan blocks.
In the past, I’ve seen students claim (without proof) that the uniqueness of the Jordan–Chevalley decomposition follows from the uniqueness of the Jordan normal form.
This has lead me to the following question:

> **Question.**
> Is there a connection between the uniqueness of the Jordan–Chevalley decomposition and the uniqueness of the Jordan normal form?

Comment: yes, both are unique up to block permutations

Comment: @Exodd I don’t see how this answers the question. And for the Jordan–Chevalley decomposition it doesn’t make sense to talk about blocks. (I think.)

Comment: The J-C decomposition is a statement about endomorphisms and the Jnf one about matrices — the latter change when you permute the basis with respect to which they are taken, but endomorphisms are completely independent of any bases.